# Stop IntelliJ code editor from escaping pasted string literal characters

Tags: java, intellij-idea, unicode, string-literals, code-editor

What I want:

```
String x = "" ;
```

What I get in Apple [*TextEdit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextEdit) 1.16 text editor app when clicking  from the macOS "Show Emojis & Symbols" floating windoid:

```
String x = "" ;
```

## Problem 1

What I get in [*IntelliJ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 2021.2.2 code editor when clicking  from the macOS "Show Emojis & Symbols" floating windoid:

```
String x = "ð" ;
```

**Update:** This appears to be a currently known bug. See issue page [*IDEA-278540 Emoji in OSX are rendered as another unicode*](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-278540), as noted in [Answer by Konstantin Annikov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69341287/642706).

## Problem 2

What I get in [*IntelliJ*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 2021.2.2 code editor when pasting that  character copied from *TextEdit* app:

```
String x = "\uD83D\uDE37" ;
```

Presumably the issue revolves around Unicode characters outside the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)).

➯ Is there any way to make the IntelliJ code editor accept such characters directly, without escaping?

Answer (score 2):

It's regression in IntelliJ IDEA. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-278540 for details.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. That accounts for the first problem. But I suspect the second problem is "feature" rather than a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Edit | Paste | Paste as Plain Text` to paste without any escaping.